# Specman how to access logic 2D array

Tags: specman

I would like to read a 2D logic array from specman.
The verilog code is:

```
logic [3:0][31:0]  logic_array;
```

How can this be done?

I access it using `logic_array[0]` I get the value of bit #0 of entry 0.

Comment: You should probably use `logic [31:0] logic_array; [0:3]` For storing 4 32 bit words.`logic_array[0]` would give you the first 32 bit word.

Comment: What are you using to connect to it? Ports or tick notation?

Answer (score 0):

logic_array: list of uint(bits:32);

keep logic_array.size() == 4;

var v1:uint(bits:32) = logic_array[0];

Access v1[0] for logic_array[0][0]